# How to draw dashed line in ARKit (SceneKit) like in the Measure app?

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit, scnnode

Just wanted to know is it possible (I know it is, but how) to draw dashed line in ARSCNView like in the Measure app?
Maybe there is a way to use scene nodes out of the box, idk.

I've been using the SCNCylinder to draw a straight line and IDK is it possible to reuse it and adjust or we have to use a really different way to make the dashed line.

```
import SceneKit

class CylinderLineNode: SCNNode {

    private(set) var cylinder: SCNCylinder
    private(set) var positionA: SCNVector3
    private(set) var positionB: SCNVector3

    init(with positionA: SCNVector3, positionB: SCNVector3, radius: CGFloat = 0.02, color: UIColor = .red) {
        self.positionA = positionA
        self.positionB = positionB
        let vector = positionB - positionA
        let height = vector.length()
        cylinder = SCNCylinder(radius: radius, height: CGFloat(height))
        cylinder.radialSegmentCount = 8
        cylinder.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = color
        super.init()
        geometry = cylinder
        position = (positionB + positionA) / 2
        eulerAngles = SCNVector3.lineEulerAngles(vector: vector)
    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the most professional solution, but I started with a very similar approach. And then added the dashed-style like follows.

First I created an image that is half white, half transparent, to create the dashed-style

Then used it in the material of the `SCNCylinder`:

```
material.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "line")!
material.diffuse.wrapS = .repeat
material.diffuse.wrapT = .repeat
material.isDoubleSided = true // Not sure if this is really needed here^
```

Next I scaled it accordingly, to repeat it (make it as fine) as I want it:

```
material.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4MakeScale(width * repeatCountPerMeter, height * repeatCountPerMeter, 1)
```

As I used a white image, I can "tint" it in any color I want:

```
material.multiply.contents = UIColor.green
```

To make it look more "2D like", ignore the lighting, using:

```
material.lighting = .constant
```

Additionally (as my Cylinder is rotated by 90°) I had to rotate the material as well:

```
let rotation = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(.pi / 2, 0, 0, 1)
material.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4Mult(rotation, material.diffuse.contentsTransform)
```

And whenever the line gets resized, update its `SCNMatrix4MakeScale` accordingly (see `width` and height`above, where for`height` I just put the diameter (2*r)).

Comment: Yep, thanks. I already came up with the same approach, so will post my solution here (it's very similar to yours).

Comment: @atereshkov hey bro where's your solution? I can't make this solution works :(

Comment: @Eddie Why does it not work for you? Maybe I could help.

Comment: @d4Rk I'm not sure where I'm missing since I don't really understand and just copy the code. Maybe the transform is missing because it's unclear to me what's `width`, `height`, and `repeatCountPerMeter`. I'm using the image created by UIGraphicContext, so probably nothing wrong with the image. maybe the contents transform is not correct? :|

Comment: @d4Rk I've posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63502194/draw-dashline-cylinder-in-scenekit-like-measure-app

Comment: I used it like `lineMaterial.scaleDiffuse(width: start.distance(to: end), height: 0.004, repeatCountPerMeter: 30)` where `start` and `end` are two `SCNVector3`s, defining the start and end of the line to be rendered.

Comment: @Eddie hey if i can recall it I was using the d4Rk approach finally, there were not big changes between my solution. So following this you should make it work